# What should i do when after executing a set of codes thein the p5 web editor says that "createSprite" fuction is not defined?

Tags: javascript, function

```
background = createSprite(20,100);
```

background.addImage(backgroundImg);
background.scale = 0.5;

//After execution the output screen shows "createSprite" not defined//

Comment: You need to import or require the file where createSprite is defined, before using it.

Comment: yes that's the question .from where can i get it ??Do I have to download this file from somewhere or i have to create this file on my own .because there are large number of such functions and it is a very hectic task to create a whole separate file for this whole set of such small functions.